# Questions about concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If I understood it correctly synchronized should be enough to make sure that only one thread at a time can access a resource:

When a thread wants to execute a synchronized block, it acquires the monitor and releases it automatically when the synchronized block is over, meanwhile every other thread that tries to access a syncrhonized block where the monitor is already being hold, is put in a queue and will keep on trying to access the synchronized method for as long as the program is running.

If I call wait() inside a synchronized block, then I could end up with multiple threads inside the synchronized block and I'm also forced to call notify() at the end of the block to avoid situations where threads are waiting forever.

- First of all, is what I just stated correct? If it is not, what's wrong?
- If it is, what are the most commons situations where synchronized should be used with wait() and notify()?
- In general, if I'm making the code more complex by adding wait() and notify() to synchronized, would it be better to just use a more sophisticated tool like ReentrantLocks?

Comment: Typically you should prefer higher level abstractions to wait() and notify() as they can be easily [misused](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=88487729#content/view/88487729). As described, a condition object is more explicit about the intents. The j.u.c. data structures should be preferred and will be less complex to reason about. Your general understandings appear correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all, is what I just stated correct? If it is not, what's wrong?

The first two paragraphs are spot on.  The third paragraph about wait / notify is mostly right.  There are a couple of points though:

- It is necessary for *some* thread to call `notify` or `notifyAll`.  But it doesn't necessarily have to be this one.
- You can call at any point, not just at the end of a block.  Either way, the notification doesn't happen until the current thread leaves the block.
- A thread waiting on a notify that never arrives is not necessarily stuck for ever.  For example, a thread interrupt will cause the `wait` to terminate with an `InterruptedException`.

---

> If it is, what are the most commons situations where `synchronized` should be used with `wait()` and `notify()`?

The word "should" is a loaded term.  The situations where you *could* use `wait()` and `notify()` are those where one thread needs to wait for some event to occur.  (Typically this is used to implement a *condition variable*.) But depending on the circumstances, there *may* be better ways to do it.

Also, you can't use `wait()` and `notify()` *without* holding the associated mutex.  (You will get an exception if you try to do that!)

---

> In general, if I'm making the code more complex by adding `wait()` and `notify()` to `synchronized`, would it be better to just use a more sophisticated tool like `ReentrantLocks`?

Not in general.

If there are higher level concurrency classes that do what you are trying to do, it is generally better to use them instead of primitive mutexes + wait / notify.  But that won't always be the case.

You mentioned `ReentrantLock`.  This class is really just mutex-like locks "on steriods".  They have a few features that are not available with primitive mutexes (like `tryLock` and seeing which threads are waiting), but if you don't *need* the extra features there is no real advantage in using `ReentrantLock` over primitive mutexes.  (One possible *disadvantage* is that `Lock` classes don't release automatically on exit of a block.  So you really need to use them in conjunction with `try ... finally` or `try` with resources.)